# Facebook login: Invalid key hash. The key hash MhmZ****** does not match any stored key hashes

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-login, keystore, sha

Im try to implement Login with Facebook feature for my Unity game. It's weird that when have the facebook app on my phone, it show the error message :
`Invalid key hash. The key hash MhmZ***************  does not match any stored key hashes`

it's weird cause when I use the openssl to create SHA key, it's different. the result is Bmce+***************

However when I delete the facebook app and try to login again, (it will login by browser) and it works.

I tried to copy the key hash in the msg  MhmZ****** and pasted on the developers page but it still not working.

I hope when user already has the facebook app, they can still login to my game.

If anybody knows why this happend please let me know. Thank you very much